# Android 4.0 - problems

Tags: android

I have 3 problems with android 4.0 (Galaxy tab 10.1).
The first one is getting local IP:
I use the method:

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works great on android v2.1-2.3. But some customers who have Android 4.0 complain me that it doesn't work! It returns something like mac-address: fe80::fad0:bdff:fe4d:4871 Can anyone explain what's happened?

The second problem is about WiFi checking state. I use function below to check connection to WiFi hotspot point:

```
 public boolean IsWiFiConnected(){
     List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
     boolean retVal=false;
        for(WifiConfiguration wifiConf : wifiConfigList){               
            if(wifiConf.status==WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT){
                retVal=true;
                break;
            }
        }
     return retVal;
 }
```

In android 4.0 it always returns false.

And the third problem is getting device's information (it happens on ASUS Transformer Prime):
I get information about device by using function below:

```
public static String GetDeviceInfo(Context context){
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    return Build.BRAND.toString()+"~|~"+Build.DEVICE.toString()+"~|~"+telephonyManager.getDeviceId().toString()+"~|~"+Build.VERSION.RELEASE;        
}
```

It throws NULLPointerExeption. I think it happens because of TelephonyManager can not be initialized. I have all permissions in manifest. These all functions work fine on the previous versions.

Could anyone tell me what's going on?
Thank you.

Comment: Please break this up into three separate questions. It goes against site rules to ask several questions in one post.